# Scrapy scraping all texts under a div

Tags: scrapy

[image: HTML Structure]

I need to do two things, first one is grabbing all the texts not inside b elements.
Second is i need to grab all the texts, texts inside b elements aswell.
My Code:

```
try:
     all_info = response.xpath("//div[@class = 'title']/div[@class='tooltipContainer']/div/text()").extract_first()
except Exception as ex:
     yield {"Ex`enter code here`": ex}
        
yield {"All_Information":all_info}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the future, please don't post code as img file, copy and paste it in the body of your question, it makes it easier for us answering.

From the snippet in the image you can use:

```
//div[@class="tooltip"]/text()
```

For the text exclusively inside the div, avoiding the text in the `<b>` tags. And:

```
//div[@class="tooltip"]//text()
```

For all text in the `div` element, including the text inside `<b>` text.

The `//` is a reference to descendant-or-self axis, you can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/descendant-or-self).

Comment: Pipped! Agree with everything said here. Particularly the image part! To the OP Would always advise using class attributes in your XPATH selector as much as possible, countless nesting becomes unreadable. Also use get() instead of extract_first(), more concise and also you know that your output will be a string. You can use getall() if you want to extract all values, this will always give you a list.